# how to copy file from remote server to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, scp, rhel

I have a remote server and servers authenticated Hadoop environment.

I want to copy file from Remote server to Hadoop machine to HDFS

Please advise efficient approach/HDFS command to copy files from remote server to HDFS.

Any example will be helpful.

as ordinary way to copy file from remote server to server itself is

```
scp -rp file remote_server:/tmp
```

but this approach not support copy directly to hdfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```sh
ssh remote-server "hadoop -put - /tmp/file" < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the remote server you mean to say it is not in the same network as the hadoop nodes. If that is the case may be you can scp from remote machine to hadoop nodes local file system and then use -put or -copyFromLocal command to move to HDFS.

example: hadoop fs -put file-name hdfs://namenode-uri/path-to-hdfs

Comment: both them are with the same network and I not want to copy to local folder , I want to copy directly to HDFS

Comment: Ok, As first step validate if you have access to the hdfs from this remote node. if you confirm that then you have the hadoop client libraries installed in the remote node and try to access the hdfs from remote. You might face write access issues from remote node. This has to be sorted out from server admin people.